# How can I send the multiple ids to controller in this view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I want to send multiple ids that selected with checkboxes to the controller in this code :

```
<% form_for :product do %>
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Select
        </th>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
        <th>
            Product Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Product Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Product Price
        </th>
        <th>
            Categories
        </th>
        <th colspan="3">
            Actions
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% @products.each do |p| %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= check_box_tag "product_ids[]", p.id, false, :id => "product_#{p.id}" %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= image_tag p.photo.url(:thumb) , :alt => "#{p.name}" %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "#{p.name}" , edit_product_path(p) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=h truncate(p.description.gsub(/<.*?>/,''),:length => 80) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=h p.price %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <% for category in p.categories.find(:all) %>
            <%= link_to "#{category.name}" , category_path(category.id) %>
            <% end %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= link_to 'Show' , product_path(p) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(p) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= link_to 'Remove', product_path(p), :confirm => "Are you really want to delete #{p.name} ?", :method => 'delete' %>
        </td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="products_nav">
    <%= link_to "Add a new Product" , new_product_path %>
    <%= link_to "Add a new Category" , new_category_path %>
    <%= link_to "Category page" , categories_path %>
    <%= link_to "Remove selected products" , delete_selected_products_path , :method => 'delete' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The code is in this line :

```
<%= link_to "Remove selected products" , delete_selected_products_path , :method => 'delete' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks OK to me, although the "delete_selected_products_path" route is not typical.  Do you have a route specifically set up for this?

In any case, you should be able to send this delete request to the usual method and have the controller check the params.

This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) may help.